# Problema con Performance con jquery y el metodo $.Get

Tags: php, jquery

Buenas tengo este código **Jquery** con el meto **$.get** el problema esta es que me demora mucho el proceso de carga alguien me da una ayuda en el performans.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.get('/rolList.php', function(result) {
    var roln = new Array([]);
    roln = $.parseJSON(result);
    $(function() {
        // setup autocomplete function pulling from currencies[] array
        $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
            lookup: roln,
            onSelect: function(suggestion) {
                var thehtml = '<strong>Currency Name:</strong> ' + suggestion.value + ' <br>';
                $('#outputcontent').html(thehtml);
            }
        });
    });
    console.log(roln);
});

// SI SOLO SE SELECCIONA EL HIJO SE AUTO CHECKEA EL PADRE
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    setTimeout(
        function() {
            $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
                var parents = $.trim($(this).parents('div.parent').text());
                var children = $.trim($(this).parents('div.checkbox').text());
                if(parents.length <= 0 && children.length > 0) {
                    var parentID = '#' + $(this).attr('id').substring(0, 2);
                    $(parentID).prop('checked', true);
                    $(parentID).parents('label').addClass('active');
                }
            });
        }, 100);
});
$('#autocomplete').keyup(function() {
    var val = $('#autocomplete').val();
    if(val === '') {
        $('input').hasClass('active').removeClass('active');
    }
});
//INPUT CUSTOMER CON AUTOCOMPLETE 

// SI EL ROL EXISTE SE GENERA SUS PERMISOS PARA ASI 
// MODIFICARLO


  // VALIDAR SI EL ROL EXISTE
            $('#autocomplete').on('change', function() {
             var roleName = $(this).val();
             var collaps='';
            $.get('/rolExists.php',{roleName : roleName,type:1}, function(resp) {
                var rol = $.parseJSON(resp);
                if(rol[0]._isValid == '1') {
                    $.get('/roleModulepermission.php', {
                            roleName: roleName
                        }, function(isV) {
                            var rmp = $.parseJSON(isV);
                            $.each(rmp, function(index, val) {
                                var parents = val.ParentsShortName;
                                var module = val.moduleShortName;

                                    if(parents == 'inv') {
                                        $('input[id*=' + parents + ']').prop('checked', true);
                                        $('input[id*=' + parents + ']').parents('label').addClass('active');
                                    } else {
                                        if(module != '#') {
                                            $('input[id=' + module + ']').prop('checked', true);
                                            $('input[id=' + module + ']').parents('label').addClass('active');
                                             collaps = $('input[id=' + parents + ']').parents("div[class=parent]").attr('href');
                                            $(collaps).addClass('show');
                                        }else{
                                            $('input[id=' + parents + ']').prop('checked', true);
                                            $('input[id=' + parents + ']').parents('label').addClass('active');
                                            collaps = $('input[id=' + parents + ']').parents("div[class=parent]").attr('href');
                                            $(collaps).addClass('show');
                                        }

                                    }
                                    if(roleName == 'Admin'){
                                        $('#autocomplete').prop('disabled', true);
                                        $("#addRol").prop('disabled', true);
                                    }else{
                                        $('#autocomplete').prop('disabled', true);
                                    }

                                });
                            });
                        }
                    });
            });


  // INSERTA O ACTUALIZAR ROLL
  var rolID = new Array();
   var formArray = new Array();
  $("#addRol").on("click", function () {
var rolns = $("#autocomplete").val();
// SE CREA EL ARRAY DE LOS MODULOS SELECCIONADOS
$.get("/moduleInfo.php", function (result) {
    var moduleInfo = new Array([]);
    moduleInfo = $.parseJSON(result);
    if (rolns !== '') {
        $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function () {
             var r = $.trim($(this).parents('div[class=checkbox]').text().toLowerCase());
             var parentsName = $.trim($(this).parents('div[class=parent]').text().toLowerCase());
            $.each(moduleInfo, function (i, val) {
                if (r == val.moduleName.toLowerCase() && r !== val.parents.toLowerCase()) {
                    var idModule = val.moduleID;
                    formArray.push({
                        "roleName": r,
                        "moduleID": idModule
                    });
                    console.log(idModule, r);
                }
                if (parentsName == val.parents.toLowerCase() && parentsName == val.moduleName.toLowerCase()) {
                    var IdParents = val.moduleID;
                    formArray.push({
                        "roleName": parentsName,
                        "moduleID": IdParents
                    });
                }
            });

        });
        console.log(formArray);
    } else {
        swal({
            type: "error",
            title: "ERROR!...",
            html: $("<div>")
                .addClass("swal2-small-title-error")
                .text("Defina el Nombre del Rol")
        });
    }
});
// SE VALIDA SI EL ROL ES PARA INSERT O ACTUALIZACION
$.get('/rolExists.php', {
    roleName: rolns,
    type: 1
}, function (isV) {
    var isValid = $.parseJSON(isV);
    if (isValid[0]._isValid == '0') {
        $.get('/rolExists.php', {
            roleName: rolns,
            type: 2
        }, function (insr) {
            rolID = $.parseJSON(insr);
            console.log(rolID);
            $.each(formArray, function (ind, val) {
                $.get('/insertRolePermission.php', {
                        roleID: rolID[0].roleID,
                        moduleID: val.moduleID
                    },
                    function (result) {});
            });
            location.reload();
        });

    } else {
        $.get('/rolExists.php', {
            roleName: rolns,
            type: 3
        }, function (exists) {
            rolID = $.parseJSON(exists); 
            $.get('/roleDeletePermission.php', {roleID: rolID[0].roleID}, function (e) {});
            $.each(formArray, function (ind, val) {
                $.get('/insertRolePermission.php', {
                        roleID: rolID[0].roleID,
                        moduleID: val.moduleID
                    },
                    function (result) {});
            });
            location.reload();
        });
    }
});
});
// LIMPIA LA PANTALLA DE ROL
$("#removeRol").on("click",function(){
 location.reload();
})
});
```

Comment: Disculpenme por la manera en que sale el codigo soy nuevo aqui gracias por su comprension

Comment: bueno para mejorar la velocidad puedes usar un **framework** nuevo como **vue.js** **react** o **angular** que incorporan DOM virtual y eso hace la experiencia del usuario mucho mas fluida y cargas mas rapidas

Answer (score 0):

Holaa,

Puedes revisar el tiempo que demora el archivo .php en resolver lo que estás devolviendo y si buscas es que el cargado inicial de tu desarrollo sea más rápido minifica los archivos .css y .js

Finalmente te dejo esta url de trucos y buenas prácticas de jquery (usar $get  te quita performance y más si lo usas demasiadas veces)
http://www.baluart.net/articulo/14-utiles-trucos-notas-y-mejores-practicas-de-jquery